How does `substitute` choose the deparsed representation of objects?
base::substitute's documentation describes it as follows:

Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse
tree as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in ‘env’, it is
unchanged.  If it is a promise object, ... the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol.
If it is an ordinary variable, its VALUE is substituted, unless ‘env’ is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is left unchanged.

In the final sentence, "value" is ambiguous: we need to put a deparsed representation of the object into the returned language object. But how is this representation chosen?
My assumption would be to use base::deparse, but it doesn't consistently work this way:
e <- new.env()
e$df <- tibble::tibble(1:5)
e$env <- new.env()
e$x <- 1

substitute(x+1, e)   # 1 + 1
substitute(df+1, e)  # list(`1:5` = 1:5) + 1 (does not match deparse(e$df))
substitute(env+1, e) # <environment> + 1     (does match deparse(e$env)) 

# if expr to substitute is a name, return the object itself 
# (no need to return a language object, no need for deparsing)
identical(substitute(df, e), e$df)
identical(substitute(env, e), e$env) 


If you want to go down that rabbit hole, you'd be better off reading the source code for the function. Start here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a8e9fb43b7b697e57fceb8e0bf34ceaaf58dd45c/src/main/coerce.c#L2872. I don't think the R language definition makes any promised about the representation.

Also would be worth reading the chapter on evaluation in Advanced R (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html) and maybe the chapter on environments (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html). Good luck!

I don't see ambiguity. "value" refers to the value bound to the symbol. The documentation clearly says:

substitute returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression
expr, substituting any variables bound in env.

Don't confuse what is printed with the actual representation of "value".
e1 <- new.env()
e1$DF <- data.frame(a = 1)

x <- substitute(DF + 1, env = e1)

print(x)
#list(a = 1) + 1

as.list(x)
# [[1]]
# `+`
# 
# [[2]]
# a
# 1 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1

str(as.list(x)[[2]])
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ a: num 1


e1$env <- new.env()
x <- substitute(env + 1, env = e1)

print(x)
#<environment> + 1

as.list(x)
# [[1]]
# `+`
# 
# [[2]]
# <environment: 0x0000025fe3a9f040>
#   
#   [[3]]
# [1] 1

call("+" , e1$env, 1)
#<environment> + 1

So, maybe your question boils down to how calls are printed? That would need a dive into the internal source code of print.default. Deparsing is involved and I believe it is equivalent to deparse1(x, control = "niceNames").
deparse1(x, control = "niceNames")
#[1] "<environment> + 1"

x <- substitute(DF + 1, env = e1)
deparse1(x, control = "niceNames")
#[1] "list(a = 1) + 1"


Makes sense. I was under the impression that the components of a language object could only be objects of type symbol, language, or a literal (eg. scalar atomic or NULL). I think this may be correct if the language object is obtained via quote, because eg.quote(1+c(1,2)) contains a nested call rather than a 2-vector. Your example seems to show that any object type can be a component of a language object, which clears up the ambiguity. Thanks

A call object isn’t the same as an expression object. A call obviously can contain anything that can be passed as a function argument. quote returns an expression not a call.

I don't think you are correct about quote. btw, the terminology for calls/expressions in R is inconsistent. typeof(quote(a+b)) == "language"; mode(quote(a+b)) == "call"; typeof(expression(a+b)) == mode(expression(a+b)) == "expression".  In my comment above, I was using "call" and "language" as synonyms. Some tidyverse functions refer to "calls" as "expressions" (eg. rlang::expr makes a "call"), but I refrain from doing so.

You are right regarding what call returns. I should have checked the documentation. Anyway, there are three types of language objects: names, calls, expressions. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Language-objects

You may know this, but the reason for having multiple terms for the same type is that S-like terminology made its way into R. I have previously read on this site that mode and storage.mode are concepts from S, and should be considered superseded by typeof, which is the R concept.  language objects (called calls in S) represent parsed expressions (using "expression" in the general sense, not the R type), and expression objects are vectors of calls

Thinking of a call as being able to contain anything that can be passed as a function argument is a nice way of motivating why they are not restricted to symbol, language, or a literal
